# How to Auto Update the CheckState of the parent nodes When Child's Changed Programmingly?

Tags: delphi, virtualtreeview

I am using Delphi XE3 with Virtual TreeView.

I have enabled the toAutoTristateTracking option.

WHen I try to change the check state of a node manually, then the affected node's checkstate will change as well.

However, when I do the same thing programmingly, for example

```
PNode^.CheckState := csMixedNormal;
```

or

```
PNode^.CheckState := csCheckedNormal;
```

Only PNode check state will be changed. The affected nodes will not change their states. Why?

Comment: Is `CheckState` node field or a property? If you are changing data directly of a node field then Virtual TreeView isn't notified corectly about the change made. This is why various properties use `Setter` method so that after changing some data necessary methods for updating the visual part of component are executed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't access `CheckState` of a node directly. Use array property `CheckState[Node: PVirtualNode]` of `TBaseVirtualTree` to read/write check state. Setting check state via the property will apply functionality related to tick boxes as well as fire appropriate events like `OnChecking`, 
`OnChecked`, `OnInitNode`, ...

This is what you should do instead:

```
VirtualStringTree1.CheckState[PNode] := csCheckedNormal;
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Also the property name is CheckState, not CheckedState. :)