# Override the way the checkbox changes in Virtual TreeView

Tags: delphi, checkbox, virtualtreeview

I am using Virtual TreeView. It seems that Virtual TreeView will automatically update the node check state when its children check states are changed. Is there a way to prevent this?

Thanks

Comment: According to [your question from few months ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58058639/how-to-auto-update-the-checkstate-of-the-parent-nodes-when-childs-changed-progr) it seems that you already know how to use `toAutoTristateTracking` option.

Comment: @PeterWolf, Thank  you very much. I forget that.